# Why I can't use const qualfier in my function?

Tags: c++

Hello I am working with C++ built-in algorithms. I have this code here:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

bool isDon(string& name) const {
    return name == "Don";
}

string names[] = {"George", "Don", "Estelle", "Mike", "Bob"};

int main() {
    string* ptr;
    ptr = find_if(names, names+5, isDon);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, compiler gives me an error ,in which my `isDon()` function decleration resides, which says that I cannot use a cv-qualifier in that function decleration. Why is that?

Comment: What would you expect the `const` to do if it were allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should be declared without the trailiing `const`. It is a free function and doesn't belong to a class, so it is not meaningful for the function to be `const`.

```
bool isDon(string const& name) {
    return name == "Don";
}
```

Note that you can also use a lambda of the form

```
ptr = find_if(names, names+5, [](string const& name){ return name == "Don"; });
```

Answer (score 3):

`const` affects (formally, qualifies) the `this` pointer. Freestanding functions don't have it: only non-static *member* functions do.

Comment: I think it would be clearer to say that it affects `this` itself.

Answer (score 2):

The `const` qualifier only refers to member functions and declare that the function does not modify the object over which that member function is invoked. The semantic is implemented by making `this` a `T const*`.

For a free function this just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Making a free-standing function `const` doesn't make any sense, only class or structure member functions can be `const`.

That's because the `const` tells the compiler that the (member) function will not modify the object instance.

Answer (score 1):

The const qualifier after a function name is for a function **INSIDE a class**; this function is Not Part of a Class; the `const` is telling the compiler the function does not modify members inside the class.

" A const qualifier can be used only for class non static member functions"

[const type qualifier soon after the function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474119/const-type-qualifier-soon-after-the-function-name)