# Removing code repetition using casting operators

Tags: c++, casting, operators

```
class nums
{  public:
   int sum(int a,int b) const
   {   
      return a+b;
   }
   int sum(int a,int b)
   {   
      return a+b;
   }
};
int main()
{
const nums a;
a.sum(5,10);
nums  b;
b.sum(1,2);
}
```

I am trying remove two functions for const objects and non const objects replace with one function using casting operators.

Comment: With what you have right now, there's no reason for a non-const version, or even a non-static version

Comment: @Ranoiaetep the idea behind this is to explore how casting operators are useful and im trying to explore that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int sum(int a,int b) const` even if the object isn't marked as `const`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3474134/14193797) answer.

So, the following code would compile:

```cpp
class nums
{  
    public:
    int sum(int a,int b) const
    {   
       return a+b;
    }

};
int main()
{
    const nums a;
    a.sum(5,10);
    nums b;
    b.sum(1,2);
}
```

[Link to Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/M63djWTYj).

Comment: Yes, that is possible but I want to explore how casting operators will work. Can we do this casting operators?

Comment: @iso42 wdym by "casting operators" ?

Comment: you can this refer to this [link](https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/typecast.php)